# x2x keeps pointer in second screen

Tags: xorg

I am trying to get this `displaylink` device going, and in the process, one of the things I am trying, is to get `x2x` working properly. I have my X server running fine on the displaylink device with

```
$ X :3  -layout displaylink -ac -novtswitch -sharevts
```

then I run

```
$ x2x  -to :3  -west
```

and I can move my mouse from my main screen (:0) to the left and it disappears from my main screen and moves into the displaylink attached screen (:3). Keyboard focus also transfers fine. However, when I then try to move it back to my main screen, the pointer then becomes cloned at the right edge of the displaylink screen, so I have a mouse pointer in both screens now, moving in both in the same way.

So how do I get x2x to make the pointer disappear from the displaylink screen when I move past the right edge? I tried the  `-big` hack but that didn't work, and instead causes a nice "flash" on my main screen whenever I go from one to the other. I tried switching the order around, making x2x treat the displaylink as the main screen, but that didn't work either.

In case it helps, Xorg.conf section for the displaylink device snippet:

```
Screen      3  "Screen-displaylink"  
 Option "AllowMouseOpenFail" "True"
 Option "AutoEnableDevices" "false"
 InputDevice    "Keyboard-void" "CoreKeyboard"
 InputDevice    "Mouse-void" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "1"
```